# ember.js cannot set property 'store' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, undefined, store

I have been trying to set up an `Ember.js` application together with a `RESTful API` i have created in Laravel.

I have encountered a problem trying to get the data trough the store, and depending on my implementation, I get different errors, but never any working implementations.

The `ember.js` guide have one example, other places have other examples, and most information I find is outdated.

Here's my current code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();


App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("world", function() {
        this.resource("planets");
    });
});

App.PlanetsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('planet');
    }
});

App.Planet = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    subjectId: DS.attr('number')
});
```

And when I try to click the link for planets, thats when the error occurs, and I get the following error right now:

```
Error while loading route: TypeError {} ember-1.0.0.js:394
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined emberdata.js:15
```

No request is sent for /planets at all. I had it working with a $.getJSON, but I wanted to try to implement the default ember-data RESTAdapter.

For reference, these are some of the implementations i've tried:

```
var store = this.get('store'); // or just this.get('store').find('planet')
return store.find('planet', 1) // (or findAl()) of store.findAll('planet');


App.store = DS.Store.create();
```

I also tried `DS.Store.all('planet')` as I found it in the ember.js api, but seemed like I ended up even further away from a solution.

Most other implementations give me an error telling me there is no such method `find` or `findAll`.

**EDIT (Solution)**
After alot of back and forward, I managed to make it work.

I'm not sure exactly which step fixed it, but I included the newest versions available from the web (Instead of locally), and the sourcecode now looks like this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("world", function() {
        this.resource("planets");
    });
});

App.PlanetsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('planet');
    }
});

App.Planet = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    subjectId: DS.attr()
});
```

Comment: Have you included `ember-data` after `ember`?

Comment: Yes, it was all working without RESTAdapter.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you had is probably due to the fact that you added a "s" plural of your objects.

**i.e.** if you use

```
App.Planets = DS.Model.extend({
})
```

you would get that error.